# System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic> does not contain a definition for 'Syncfusion' Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm working with ASP.Net MVC 3 with the Razor engine and version 9.104.0.20 of the SyncFusion mvc control suite.

In the documentation for this control, I am to put lines of code similar to the below in my master page:

```
@Html.Syncfusion().ScriptManager()
```

Per the Syncfusion documentation and [this Stack Overflow suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217350/why-dont-my-htmlhelper-extensions-work), I have made sure to add the namespaces to my web.config file under the  element.

```
   <add namespace="Syncfusion.Mvc.Schedule"/>
```

The solution builds but I get the following error when I run it:

> 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Syncfusion' and no extension method 'Syncfusion' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I don't think this issue has to do with Syncfusion but instead with my inability to reference their assemblies correctly.

How do I address this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The issue was resolved by adding the namespace reference in the  element.

I had to add the following configSection information at the top of the web.config:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
```

And then I had to add the SyncFusion namespaces within that defined section:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Collections" />
        <add namespace="Syncfusion.Mvc.Shared"/>
        <add namespace="Syncfusion.Mvc.Schedule"/>
        <add namespace="Syncfusion.Mvc.Tools"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: Great answer! I ran into several on the topic and most miss the adding the reference in the configSections

Comment: Thanks. It's wild this many people are still having this issue.

Comment: I would recommend removing version info from type in config.  Just use "type, assembly" and it will continue to work.  This removes maintenance when upgrading mvc2,3,4,5, razor, entlib,  - and assemblybinding redirect does the rest.  I had to apply this fix to root, areas, views web.config files and all my pages began to work aftewards.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to close Visual Studio and reopen after implementing @YeahStu 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you need to copy DevExpress/any other namespaces from the ~/Web.config configuration file to the ~/View/Web.config configuration file or any other Web.config file

This was the solution I used with worked PERFECTLY

Answer (score 0):

I just recently installed the Syncfusion.EJ2 package and the latest documentation didn't mention adding any of that extra stuff to the Web.config file. If you have multiple 'Views' folders though, make sure you add the Syncfusion.EJ2 namespace to all of Web.config files inside of those folders (or wherever you'll use their controls).

```html
 <system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      ...
      <add namespace="Syncfusion.EJ2"/>
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```